# Can a god ever be disproved

Tags: theology, evolution

Given the ability to travel to another universe, meet aliens which would otherwise show the creation of our universe and yet many others and in fact have proof of our creation accidental or otherwise would this in anyway dis prove any notion of a God therein. How?

Comment: Quite unclear... "why are we all not Chinese?" Because Chinese are chinese and Indian are indian and so on (origins, culture, society, and so on).

Comment: "Its manifest moderns humans have Chinese origin to me" manifest ???

Comment: "Is this rhetoric?" YES.

Comment: The issue is: "first" in time? Yes/no according to historical timeline. We have the historical records and reliable theories. Thus, no specific issue here.

Comment: "first" in terms of reciprocal influence? This is more complex: we have records about "western" and chinese contacts but the influence on ancient Greece was mainly Egyptian and Babylonian. Again, nothing philosophical here.

Comment: "firs" in term "prominence"? On what ground? In terms of current "state of the world"? It changes in time.

Comment: If anyone is confused by the answers: OP replaced one question with a totally different one. Just a bit of trolling.

Answer (score 1):

What a ridiculous post.

The first human cultures? There are a series of steps, like the Beaker people with ceramics, Clovis people with sewing, Gobekli Tepe with agriculture, then animal domestication which co-emerged with writing in at least three separate places, Mesopotemia, China, and South America.

The human lineage came out of Africa from a population that went through a long genetic bottleneck probably due to an eruption 70,000 years ago. Previous waves of hominid ancestors criss-bred at low levels, neanderthals in Europe & Asia where adaptations to low light levels gave key advantages, and denisovans in Asia who had high-altitude adaptations that allowed crossing of the Himalayas. So we know the principal early flow was *to* not *from* China.

Mathematics also has many steps of development. Basic geometry, zero, infinity, and the 'Arabic' numeral system [were developed in India](https://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/p0038xb0). Ancient Greeks developed most of the grounding of mathematics. Algebra was developed in the Islamic world.

Why would you think the Mongolian people are ethnically Chinese? China has an exceptionally long history of being settled in large cities. Mongols are nomadic. That difference keeps ethnic groups distinct all over the world.

The Chinese emperor was never a shogun, no emperor was. It is a specific term for 'war leader' in Japan, who became powerful enough to make the actual Japanese emperor a powerless figurehead.

Why the modern age didn't begin in China despite it's cornerstones being invented there (gunpowder, magnetic compass, canals, paper, printing), is called the Needham Question.

'Imho', lol. Read dome books, rather than picking random lists of Wikipedia pages. Making up historical just-so stories to suit your racial biases went out with the Nazis.

Comment: 1) Nomads of china are African
2) The Emperor had Shoguns (generals)
3) Thank you for your information!

Comment: 1) What could that even mean? 2) Do you mean China had war leaders? Through much of their history this was limited to eunuchs, the only men who could enter the Forbidden City. Shogun means https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shogun

Comment: `eunuch` or `Enoch` s a name of the individual who is likely responsible for construction of the great pyramids.

Comment: Nomads were banned from the city and considered animals even if they were previously a shogun, ie exiled.

Comment: Why are you misusing the word shogun? Why on Earth would you link Enoch & eunuchs, based on such a superficial similarity of phonemes?